# Angularjs directive within ng-repeat not updating outside controller data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, isolate-scope

I have a isolate scope directive that I am using inside `ng-repeat`, which is iterating over an array from the controller of that template. The template is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script1.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="AddNewTest" ng-controller="AddNewController">
    <div class="items" ng-repeat="row in rows">
      <add-new-row data="row" index="$index"></add-new-row>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

The directive is defined as follows:

```
angular.module('AddNewTest', []).
directive('addNewRow', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    controller: 'AddNewController',
    link: function (scope, element, attribute) {
      element.on('keyup', function(event){
        if(scope.index + 1 == scope.rows.length) {
          console.log('keyup happening');
          $timeout(function () {
            scope.rows.push({ value: '' });
            scope.$apply();
          });
        }
      })
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      index: '='
    },
    template: '<div class="add-new"><input type="text" placeholder="{{index}}" ng-model="value" /></div>'
  }
}).
controller('AddNewController', function ($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.rows = [
    { value: '' }
  ];
});
```

But even after adding new row and doing a `$apply()` the ng-repeat is not rendering the new data added. Please help.

[Plnkr Link Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/c7cmXaqQ0cRBKGX8SztH)

Comment: You have **isolate scope** in directive. Pass array of `rows` in directive. Like this `scope: {
      index: '=', rows:"="
    }`.Don't create rows in controller `AddNewController`. Remove `$scope.rows = [
    { value: '' }
  ]`.

Comment: How do you want this to work? An input for each value? Only 1 input that is used to push into the array? What result do you expect?

Comment: @gyc I would like to add new row on keyup event in the last row.

Answer (score 1):

Pass array of rows to directive as follow:-

```
 scope: {
  index: '=',
  rows :'='
},

<add-new-row rows="rows"  index="$index"></add-new-row>
```

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3z8Agewwtzh6qNcKwESc?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Removing the controller from directive defination helped update of ng-repeat on row update.

Answer (score 1):

Each ng-repeat creates an isolated scope than you declare an isolated scope inside your directive that has the same controller as the div. You're swimming in the $scope soup :)

I would personnally make a clean and independent directive with its own controller.

```
angular.module('AddNewTest', []).
directive('addNewRow', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: MyController,
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
    template: '{{$ctrl.rows.length}}<div class="add-new"><pre>{{$ctrl.rows | json}}</pre><input type="text" placeholder="0" ng-model="value" /></div>'
  }
}).
controller('MyController', MyController);

function MyController($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  this.rows = [ { value: '' } ];

   $scope.$watch("value",function(value){
     if(value)
      vm.rows.push({ value: value });
   });
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/AvjXWWKMz0RKSwvYNt6a?p=preview

Of course you can still bind some data to the directive using `bindToController` (instead of scope:{}) and if you need an ng-repeat, do it in the directive template directly.

Comment: Yeah. My bad. I use seperate controller for each directive i create. But this time i messed up trying to reuse the same as for the global template as.